Ruby on Rails: Render.com is not picking up my stylesheet from application.html.erb
Note that my question is similar to: tailwind.css not being generated in a Rails 7 project in Heroku
So when I run my rails app locally everything works fine. But when I deploy it to Render, I get this error:
Showing /app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

The asset "tailwind.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.


I have tried running rake assets:precompile locally in my project then redeploying to Railway and I still get the error. I have also tried running bin/rails assets:clean assets:precompile and then redeploying and I also still get the error.

app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css is compiled by tailwind into
app/assets/builds/tailwind.css
tailwind.css is the file that's precompiled by sprockets:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>

https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails#configuration-and-commands

Even when I change it to that and do bin/rails assets:clean assets:precompile, it still fails with the same error.

@Slaknation what's in your manifest.js?

//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
//= link_tree ../builds
//= link application.tailwind.css

@Slaknation //= link_tree ../builds should be enough. looks like a railway issue, i'm not familiar with it. but in general, when you deploy you're using a web server like nginx to serve precompiled assets from public/assets, which needs to be configured in nginx.conf.

So would you say that I'm screwed (on this issue)? I might try deploying to render.

@Slaknation either you need to add nginx https://railway.app/template/o3MbZe to your set up or enable rails to serve static assets in production https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-public-file-server-enabled

After struggling for hours with this, I simple added the following lines to my assets.rb file:
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/assets/builds")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/assets/")

I hope this helps.

here it depends on which stage the project.
1- New rails app
if the project is new just try to recreate with tailwind css flag. that works out of the box
rails new MY_NEW_APP_NAME --css tailwind

2- existing app
you can check that you have the right configuration as mentioned on tailwind's website
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails
3- Need a quick fix and comeback to this later
it is possible to use a cdn temporarily
 <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

4- debug the issue
check if the css file exists on heroku
add a bash file to execute deployment and precompile css
precompile css on heroku terminal (I have tried this in AWS before and it worked )
5 - check manifest you might need add a link
6 - import tailwind functions inside your main css file
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

